# Update Database from changes made in a DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql, workflow-foundation

I attached the DataBase DataSet to a DataGridView to automatically display its content

But now i need to collect the changes made in this DGV to update my database 
How can i do that?

Comment: -1 for removing the code example you provided before...  Some code is better than no code at all... I'm struggling to see any research attempt here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `SqlCommandBuilder` to create and execute an `Update` command:

```
    private void UpdateDatabase()
    {
        //Create an adapter to get the schema and point to the correct table
        //Can do something like SELECT * from table_name where 0 = 1
        SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(yourSelectString, yourConnectionString);
        SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapt);

        try
        {
            adapt.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
            ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Handle any exception here
        }
    }
```

This dynamically creates an `Update` command based on any changes in your `DataTable`.

**Edit**

The Code you provided (and removed for some reason), was correctly binding the `DataSet` to your `DataGridView`.  When you make changes to the values in the cells of the `DataGridView` it automatically changes the underlying `DataTable` (in your case `ds.Tables[0]`.  In order to send the changes back to the Database, using the method above will automatically create and execute a SQL `Update` command sending the changes back to the Database.

Comment: All you did was remove the code example from your question.  Which did not clarify anything at all.  You want to call the method I provided `UpdateDatabase()` wherever you want to submit changes from your `DataTable`.

Comment: What do you mean `All the time`?  Are you getting an error?  If so what is the error.  Are you handling exceptions in the `catch` block?  Without actually seeing your code in the context of your program it is pretty hard to tell what might be going wrong.

Comment: no no errors... but sometimes when i reload data it returns as it was before i update it

Comment: could the problem be from the reload method!

Comment: try calling `ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges()` after the Update is called.  If that isn't working then try to re-query your database after the update transaction has completed.

Comment: this.familiesTableAdapter.Fill(this.familiesDataSet.Families);
how can i re-query it?

Comment: I think there is something else going wrong in your code.  Either re-post it or I will not be able to help any further unfortunately.